# How to create and send Flashbot bsc?

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, bsc, binance-smart-chain, flashbots

I'm trying to redeem some ERC tokens lost in a metamask, I found this code from Flashbots https://github.com/flashbots/searcher-sponsored-tx

turns out that my tokens are on the bsc network, I made some changes to the code without success, my changes:

```
const ETHEREUM_RPC_URL = process.env.ETHEREUM_RPC_URL || "https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443"
   const provider = new providers.StaticJsonRpcProvider(ETHEREUM_RPC_URL);
   const flashbotsProvider = await FlashbotsBundleProvider.create(provider, walletRelay);
```

but without success, is there any way to use this method in the bsc chain?, what do i need to change in this code

Answer (score 0):

As of writing (May 2022), geth-fb miners and the Flashbot rpc endpoint are only available on Ethereum mainnet and Goerli testnet (https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/searchers/quick-start)

Answer (score -2):

You could try to do this:

```
const PRIVATE_KEY_EXECUTOR = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_EXECUTOR || "XXXXXX"
const PRIVATE_KEY_SPONSOR = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_SPONSOR || "XXXXXX"
const FLASHBOTS_RELAY_SIGNING_KEY = process.env.FLASHBOTS_RELAY_SIGNING_KEY || "XXXXXX";
const RECIPIENT = process.env.RECIPIENT || "XXXXXX"

[....]

  const ETHEREUM_RPC_URL = process.env.ETHEREUM_RPC_URL || "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
  const provider = new providers.StaticJsonRpcProvider(ETHEREUM_RPC_URL);
  const flashbotsProvider = await FlashbotsBundleProvider.create(provider, walletRelay);

[...]


  const tokenAddress = "CONTRACT_ADDRESS_HERE";
  const engine: Base = new TransferERC20(provider, walletExecutor.address, RECIPIENT, tokenAddress);
```

Then inside the `bundleTransaction:` specify your transaction configuration.

Hope it helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).